# How to scroll to a selected item in a ScrolledListBox in python?

Tags: python, listbox, scroll, tkinter, listboxitem

I am developing an application that displays a large database of items.

There is also a search bar allowing the user to search that database rather than scrolling through each item to find the one they need. When the search returns `True` (a match was made) the information needed shows up in a textbox and more options in another listbox (not scrolled now), but the `ScrolledListBox` does not auto-scroll to the selected item even if I am using `selection_set()` or `list_box.active()`.

I got it! I had to use the `list_box.yview_scroll()` command! That takes 2 arguments: 
1) The integer/index of where to go
2) Line by line or by pages(UNITS or PAGES)

But I do find the .see method to be more efficient!

Comment: Post what you tried (and accept some answers).

Comment: (I didn't realize you had to click the check to accept the answer) Like I said: I tried the list_box.activate(index) as well as the list_boxselection_set(index) there was one more, but I cant recall it. Also index is the item that needs to be selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tkinter doesn't have a ScrolledListBox class. Can you be more specific about which ScrolledListBox implementation you're using?

That being said, the scrollable widgets in Tkinter typically have a `see` method that will scroll enough to make sure the passed-in index is visible.

In the comment to this answer you say you are using pmw.ScrolledListBox. According to [the documentation for the ScrolledListBox widget](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/ScrolledListBox.html):

> In addition, methods from the Tkinter.Listbox class are forwarded by this megawidget to the listbox component.

Therefore, you can call any method on that widget that you can call on a Listbox widget. As I mentioned earlier, the Listbox class has a `see` method, so you should be able to do something like:

```
the_widget.see(index)
```

In the above example `index` is the row in the listbox you want to see.

Comment: I am using the python mega widget module(Pmw) for this, and it really is a ScrolledListBox. Using Python 2.7 –